# Using MemoryStream and DotNetZip to zip a json file

Tags: c#, json, memorystream, dotnetzip

I have a JSON file created, and I am going to zip it using DotNetZip.
Using with StreamWriter to zip it is working, if I try to use MemoryStream it will not working.

StreamWriter :

```
sw = new StreamWriter(assetsFolder + @"manifest.json");
sw.Write(strManifest);
sw.Close();
zip.AddFile(Path.Combine(assetsFolder, "manifest.json"), "/");
zip.AddFile(Path.Combine(assetsFolder, "XXXXXXX"), "/");
zip.Save(outputStream);
```

MemoryStream :

```
var manifestStream = GenerateStreamFromString(strManifest);
public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
zip.AddEntry("manifest.json", manifestStream);  
zip.AddFile(Path.Combine(assetsFolder, "XXXXXXX"), "/");
zip.Save(outputStream);
```

I must using the .JSON file type to zip it, Can any one told me where have a mistake?

Comment: That looks correct. Are you sure that your paths are set correctly?

Comment: If I understand correctly you wanted to `gzip` your `JSON`, am I right?

Comment: @Leon Husmann Yes the path of assetsFolder is correct, is it `zip.AddEntry` really create a stream area for saving that json file?

Comment: @Ali Yes you are right

Comment: @YukwongTsang yes, it should. May you try this: [DotNetZip Examples](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples)

Answer (score 0):

To create a **Gzipped** **Json** you need to use `GZipStream`. Try method below.

https://www.dotnetperls.com/gzipstream

> GZipStream compresses data. It saves data efficiently—such as in
>   compressed log files. We develop a utility method in the C# language
>   that uses the System.IO.Compression namespace. It creates GZIP files.
>   It writes them to the disk.

```
    public static void CompressStringToFile(string fileName, string value)
    {
        // A.
        // Write string to temporary file.
        string temp = Path.GetTempFileName();
        File.WriteAllText(temp, value);

        // B.
        // Read file into byte array buffer.
        byte[] b;
        using (FileStream f = new FileStream(temp, FileMode.Open))
        {
            b = new byte[f.Length];
            f.Read(b, 0, (int)f.Length);
        }

        // C.
        // Use GZipStream to write compressed bytes to target file.
        using (FileStream f2 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(f2, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
        {
            gz.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I have a question for it. GZipped required to create a real file to write the string into stream,  is there have any method without using a real filestream? Anyway, Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Could you please describe more? create a real file?